# PHP: When should I check optional parameter type for array?

Tags: php, arrays, parameters, null, option-type

What is the best way to check for optional parameter type in a function?  Every example I've seen so far has been of style 2 below.  Is that a better way than option 1, or only because you can't check for some things in the parameters directly?  I need my optional parameter to be an array if it is passed.

1)

```
public function foo($reqData, array $optData = NULL) {
  ...
  if ($optData) {
    foreach ($optData...
  }
}
```

OR
2)

```
public function foo($reqData, $optData = NULL) {
  ...
  if (is_array($optData)) {
    foreach ($optData...
  }
}
```

Comment: How about both? `if ($optDat !== NULL && is_array($optData))`

Comment: In the first example the $optData needs to be provided as an array. The second one can be a single value variable, where it can also be an array. That is why it is investigated with "is_array". Both are doing the same thing

Comment: I know they are both ending with the same result, I was wondering if I was missing something because every example I've been able to find was the second style, when the first style is much more intuitive to me (at least coming from my background with strongly-typed languages).

Answer (score 0):

Second option is generally preferable, because if you pass in something OTHER than an array, you get a fatal error:

```
function foo1 (array $opt) { var_dump($opt); }
function foo2 ($opt = null) { var_dump($opt); }

foo2(array('bar')); // dumps out an array with 'bar' in it
foo1('bar'); // catchable fatal error
```

If PHP had function overloading, it wouldn't be an issue

Answer (score 0):

An interest of OOP is to add constraints to avoid bugs. If you follow this idea, the first way seems better.

A lot of PHP developpers are not used strictly coding as in C, because PHP is flexible/permissive by nature and don't give habit to be the most restrictive.